Which is correct for writing statstics in a sentence in APA style: zero or 0? One or 1?
Example:

The indicator variable equals one if both companies are located in the same country, and zero otherwise.

Or:

The indicator variable equals 1 if both companies are located in the same country, and 0 otherwise.


I'm not sure where this question is supposed to go -- it is quite certainly off-topic here. Did you check their style guide?

I disagree with closure. On CV we know a great deal about statistics; many of us are well-informed about writing. Conversely, typical experts on language know little about statistics. With nothing else said, the first rule is consistency , use words consistently or numerals consistently, but you're there already. After that, the usual advice about writing (in English) to prefer words for small integers seems of doubtful relevance to writing on statistics (or indeed mathematics). If the context is numerical values, I prefer numerals 0 and 1, but you may have a fight to get that accepted.

I disagree with closure. The definition of the "Reporting" tag reads, "Guidelines for presenting results of a statistical analysis in a research manuscript, presentation, or for general public." I think this question falls under that definition. This is a question that experienced statisticians are most qualified to answer.

"I will appreciate it you can cite an authority for your answer." The authority for APA style is the APA Style Guide. What more is there to do than find a copy and read it?

Agreed with Sycorax's last comment. If the APA style guide says nothing about it (I don't know if it's the case), that means they let you some freedom relative to this. In that case, what to do depends on the circumstances that make you ask this question in the first place (e.g. is it relative to a paper you intend to publish somewhere?), so your question could be improved by giving more context. To give an example, the Journal of Animal Ethics recommends to use the Chicago Manual of Style when a point is not addressed by the APA style guide. Rules may be different for other journals.

This site at Purdue represents itself as consistent with the APA style guide and the advice on numbers also seems sensible.

I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about statistics, but about writing conventions, and it has garnered non-responsive answers. The authority on APA is the APA Style Guide. If OP is correct in claiming that the guide is silent on this issue, then there isn’t an authoritative answer and OP will need to figure out the standard for the publication or venue is relevant to them — not a statistical topic.

However, the answer to OP's question is in the style guide, and it's exactly where you'd expect, in the section Numbers & Statistics: "Use a numeral in these cases: [...] a number denoting: time, a date, an age, a point on a scale, an exact amount of money, or a numeral (the 3 key on your keyboard, 7 years old, a 5 on the test)." In light of this, it's hard to believe that OP "researched the question thoroughly." Note that even though the answer is in the style guide, the question is still not on-topic because it is solely about writing conventions, not statistics.

The [tag:reporting] tag is for guidelines about presenting statistical results — how to be clear in communicating about statistical topics, how to not be misleading with statistics, things of that nature. This question is purely stylistic, and its connection to statistics is incidental. Everyone knows that one and 1 are the same number, so there’s no statistical communication issue at work here. It strains credulity to believe that every style guide question about numbers and every question about written communication involving numbers is on-topic at a statistics site.

There’s no evidence anywhere that this is a statistical question at all! Your elaboration (that you read the APA guide but don't know how to apply its contents) is (1) nowhere present in the question, so we're left to assume you haven't even read the guide and (2) demonstrates that this is a question about interpreting the style guide. Ask someone who knows about style guides, not statisticians -- our opinion is irrelevant, because we are not an authority on APA style.

Answer from the APA's own style expert for statisticians who publish papers: it should be "The indicator variable equals 1 if both companies are located in the same country, and 0 otherwise." Thanks to those who tried to help.
